# Integrate Jsf application into Liferay

Tags: jsf-2, liferay, liferay-6

I am developing a JSF 2.0 (with primefaces 3.2) application, and I want to integrate my JSF application inside Liferay. I am new to Liferay and the requirement is that the application will have entrance through Liferay.

That means User will login, which should happen through Liferay. Then as I have seen in liferay basic videos after login in liferay 'Liferayhomepage' comes.

Now please guide me, inside that homepage or after login I should be able to see a JSF application that I am developing, (you can say my application will be a portlet inside liferay) right? and should be able to navigate according to 'roles' that you have applied in Liferay. How can I do that?

> Second question is once I have entered inside my JSF aplication, definitely
>   I will need 'userId' which will be unique, to perform insertion and
>   retrieval of data from database. How can I use it inside my JSF
>   applcation? If anybody can explain with a simple example, it will be
>   really helpful, as this is the point where I am stuck. Please help
>   me out.
>
> In short is it possible to call separate JSF application through
>   liferay? here I am giving entrance through liferay because liferay provides "roles", so that once the logs in through liferay he should be able to enter my JSF application based on the roles (like admin, power user etc..) (This is what exactly I want to do)

Please let me know if anybody needs more clarification on my question.

Comment: Clarification required: You already have a complete standalone JSF web application developed and you want to integrate it with Liferay? Or you will be developing a new application using JSF in Liferay?

Comment: I already have a complete jsf web application,and I want to integrate it with liferay.

Comment: Then I guess you would have to use the iframe technique mentioned in this link: http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+Web+Application+Integrator. But you won't be able to use liferay's roles and permissioning system.

Comment: But if you are really keen on using lifray's roles & permissions than you probably have to create a new JSF portlet in liferay and migrate your code to suit the portlet environment and use Liferay's permissioning system within your JSPs, and for this you already have two good answers as to how to develop JSF portlets in liferay. I am afraid you can't use the code of your JSF web-application as it is in the JSF portlet you would develop.

Comment: Thanks Prakash for your helpful guidence.Now I can take a good decision. I will migrate my jsf code into a jsf-portlet. You can use your comments as a answer, so you will get points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as Mark already mentioned you can find jsf portlet examples (also with primefaces) here http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-faces/demos

inside your jsf portlet you can get the user object (containing the roles) by this way:

```
public static User getCurrentUser(){
    User u = null;
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = fc.getExternalContext();
    if (externalContext.getUserPrincipal() != null) {
        Long id = Long.parseLong(externalContext.getUserPrincipal().getName());
        try {
            u = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserById(id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return u;
}
```

Comment: Yes, But I am actually trying to enter in to my jsf application which is not jsf-portlet,its simply separate jsf(web) application.In that case how can I pass userid of lifery login user to my jsf application.?

Comment: if you use your standalone app via iframe on the portal page I don't think that it is possible to do what you want

Comment: You must migrate your standalone app to portlet. That isn't so hard, you can reuse your beans and faces. Portlet is only the new start point of you app. Try the example from Miha link.

Answer (score 1):

Install Liferay IDE and its help you to create simple JSF-2 Portlet. You found some examples at portletfaces page
http://www.portletfaces.org/projects/portletfaces-bridge/liferay-ide

fyi portlet-faces is now liferay-faces: http://www.portletfaces.org/projects/liferayfaces

Comment: yes, there is a way in liferay where you can create jsf-2 portlet.So do you mean that I need to fit my existing jsf application as a portlet ?

Comment: Yes, so you adapted the app to portlet.

Comment: Its good,can you provide me any simple jsf portlet example , so I can adjsut my existing project into that.

Comment: you can create new simple JSF-Portlet with Liferay IDE that is a set of eclipse plugins. If you don't want use Liferay IDE you can create same jsf-portlet with liferay sdk, that is batch- ant-scripts. The batch command is: "create MyJSFTest MyJSFTestPortlet jsf"

Comment: yes you are right, but if I want to use my jsf application as a separate and need to call from liferay(say from view.jsp) in that case how can I do that? is it possible  to call separate jsf application through  liferay ?(This is exactly I want to do)(I have also updated my question a bit)

Comment: Here is direct link to primefaces portlet source: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-faces/tree/master/demos/bridge/primefaces3-portlet

Answer (score 1):

You should get the Liferay IDE and create a new project File->New->Liferay Project. Then select Portlet give the project a name and Display name

[image: screenShotOne]

then select JSF2.x and PrimeFaces

[image: ScreenShot2]

You should end up with something like:
[image]

you add portlets by adding information in liferay-display.xml, liferay-portlet.xml, and portlet.xml. portlet.xml will map the jsf page to the portlet view

```
    <init-param>
    <name>javax.portlet.faces.defaultViewId.view</name>
    <value>/views/view.xhtml</value>
    </init-param>
```