# How to make separate web application in Liferay?

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay, liferay-6

Today I read about Liferay. I have referred liferay.com and found one community demo application which I have run successfully.

But,my question is  that, Can I make separate web application ? like in spring (not a portal which have to include in the demo application).

```
Using community edition.
```

Thanks.. :)

Comment: May be this is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257967/integrate-jsf-application-into-liferay, can read the comments to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mark has said Liferay is a portal, and is itself a Web Application running on a Application Server like Tomcat.

If you wanted to create a separate web application using Spring, you could deploy this onto the same Application Server as Liferay, but it wouldn't run inside Liferay, it would run along side it.

You might be better to clarify what you're asking :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't no exactly what you mean, but Liferay is Portal. That is not a Web framework like spring, that is technology to setting up a portal and customize it.