# How to use Liferay features in my web application

Tags: web-applications, liferay

I am new to Liferay. I have gone through its features and they are really awesome under single roof.

My requirement is - I want to build a java web application using Liferay's features like - Alloy UI, Web Content Management, Role-Based workflow, authentication & authorization etc but this application should not be deployed on Portal because we do not require all the portal features and it will be overhead to us.

Is there any way that I can use Liferay's features in my web application and directly deploy it on web/application server?

I have found one result with title "[How to make separate web application in Liferay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383962/how-to-make-separate-web-application-in-liferay)"
but it does not say if we can use liferay features in our own web application.

Answer (score 1):

By your query, I can say that you want to use almost 90% of the Liferay portal (CMS,Alloy UI, Workflow, authentication etc) and still, you don't want portal feature. Please refer below

1) All the web apps that you refer here (WCM, workflow apps, authentication (login part)) are portlets, they are not simple servlets. So, you have to have a portal container to run portlets

2) It is not easy to take out portlets and make them normal web apps.

So, here what you can do is

1) Most Liferay portlets do provide web services. You can call those web services from your web application and use Liferay features, but you will not get the good UI and not alloy UI features. alloy is available as separate framework, so you have to integrate by your own.

2) Rather than removing portal part, Liferay provides many customization to enable/disable portal features. Try to study portal.properties file, there also you can shutdown many portal like feature.

After all, portal is also a traditional Java EE web app, which provides one more level of abstraction! :)

Cheers